# Global project variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let me start by saying I know that using `static` is the default method of using global variables. However, it doesn't work for me.

I've got this (very simple) Class:

```
public class GameSettings
{
    public static Boss chosenBoss;
}
```

Which I set from another class, depending on user input, for example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChooseMort : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Boss mort;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
    }

    void OnMouseOver(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            GameSettings.chosenBoss = mort;
            Application.LoadLevel("MainGame");
        }
    }
}
```

I then attempt to access this variable once the main scene starts like so:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    boss = GameSettings.chosenBoss;
    PositionBoss ();
    ...
}
```

However, whenever I get to the `boss = GameSettings.chosenBoss` - It's always `null`.

I've also tried `Singletons` after researching and stumbling on to this post: [Singletons](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton)

But unfortunately these didn't work for me either. I fear that I'm missing something really simple. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug your code. You can use Unity's debug option to see the values of the variables in the inspector menu. To do that, simply choose debug mode from top right corner (http://i.imgur.com/xCB6gTb.png). Check to see if your object is persistent between scenes and variables have their intended values. If the object is destroyed on load, you need to fix your singleton logic.

Comment: I use the debugger religiously. That's how I know the value is null. My question is,  why? I thought static vars were project wide. But apparently not.

Comment: Are you sure `public Boss mort;` has its value set?

Comment: What is the base type of Boss? Can it be serialized in Unity?

Comment: You haven't defined GameSettings as a static class,,, so doesn't that mean you have to new it into existance..? GameSettings GS = new GameSettings();.... If you are trying to reference it via the class then doesn't it need to be: public static class GameSettings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to reference `GameSettings` as if it were a static class. ie..

`boss = GameSettings.chosenBoss;`

and

`GameSettings.chosenBoss = mort;`

First you need to instantiate that class in order to use it, because you're not using a static class, or singleton.. (which confuses me slightly as I'm not certain as to why you will need multiple GameSettings..)

Anyway,,

```
public class ChooseMort : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Boss mort;
    private GameSettings gameSettings;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        gameSettings = new GameSettings();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
    }

    void OnMouseOver(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            gameSettings.chosenBoss = mort;
            Application.LoadLevel("MainGame");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I'd (stupidly) forgotten to make the class itself static. Thank you. I feel like an idiot!

Comment: Happens to everyone don't worry haha